# Infinite Scroll on Quora using Selenium in Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, infinite-scroll, quora

I try to handle the "infinite scrolling" in Quora website.
I use selenium lib with Python after trying to use the send_keys methods i try to run Javascript command in order to scroll down the page.

It doesn't working when i run the code, but if i try to run in the firefox console it's work.
How can i fix this problem? and it's possibile use PhantomJs?

```
def scrapying(self):
    print platform.system()

        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        #browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')

    browser.get("https://www.quora.com/C-programming-language")
    #browser.get("https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index?sid=396545660")
    time.sleep(10)

    #elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("topic_page content contents main_content fixed_header ContentWrapper")
    no_of_pagedowns = 500

    while no_of_pagedowns:
        #elem.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        no_of_pagedowns -= 1

    browser.quit()






myClassObject = getFrom()
myClassObject.scrapying()
```

Comment: What page exactly on quora are you interested in scrolling? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i edit now the code. The page that i'm interessed is this one https://www.quora.com/C-programming-language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the options would be to recursively *[scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the last loaded post on a page*:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/C-programming-language")

NUM_POSTS = 200
posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.pagedlist_item")

while len(posts) < NUM_POSTS:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", posts[-1])

    posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.pagedlist_item")

    print(len(posts))
```

And it would scroll the page down until, at least, `NUM_POSTS` posts are loaded.

Comment: I try to run this code but i don't receive any feedback, on firefox or in the string in the terminal. You use Chrome like driver? but firefox js function?

Comment: @RedVelvet okay, can you try it in Chrome?

Comment: Yea you take the point!
It works with chrome, however why doesn't on firefox and how i can try the same thing on phantomJs is more important for my project.
I try to use time.sleep(3) too

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not able to trigger the *infinite scroll* to work using this while using Firefox. The gist of the code works in the console, however:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
```